# How to type hint object wrapped in a Mock?

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

I commonly use `unittest.mock.Mock`'s `wraps` functionality to create fully-functioning spy objects.

Here's an example that works fine when run:

```py
from threading import Event
from typing import Union
from unittest.mock import Mock

spy_event: Union[Mock, Event] = Mock(wraps=Event())

spy_event.set()
assert spy_event.is_set()

# How can I type hint so this error doesn't show up from mypy?
spy_event.set.assert_called_once_with()  # error: Item "function" of
# "Union[Any, Callable[[], None]]" has no attribute "assert_called_once_with"
```

You can see, the `Union[Mock, Event]` type hint isn't working out.

How can I properly type hint an object wrapped in a `Mock`?

---

**Versions**

```
Python==3.8.6
mypy==0.812
```

Comment: Why are you annotating `spy_event` as `Union[Mock, Event]`?

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/6713#issuecomment-620600319

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`spy_event` is just a `Mock`. Annotate it as a `Mock`:

```
spy_event: Mock = Mock(wraps=Event())
```

I don't know why you did that `Union` thing - you may be misunderstanding what `Union` means.